# Fonts rendered incorrectly on SVG (Depending on browser)

Tags: css, svg, fonts

I have this SVG:

http://wefix.cf/Resources/wefix2.svg

The problem is that in Chrome, it looks fine, but when switching to Internet explorer, the font is changed.
The font that i am using is Arial Rounded MT.

I also want to convert the svg to a png, but every online service that does this returns the image with a different font. Why is this happening?

As a temporary solution, I have an IE query so that when the browser is IE, this image will be displayed:

http://wefix.cf/Resources/wefix.svg

Which does not appear good on Chrome...

I can't get the svg to work cross browser for some reason. I can't convert any of them to a png, it keeps returning the image with false font.

Comment: Why can't you use Inkscape?

Comment: Can you open the svg in illustrator. If so, you transform the font into regular path. So the browser will interpret it as a vector drawing and not like a font on every browser.

Comment: When i open it in Illustrator it gives me a lot of errors and is displayed incorrectly, no blur on shadow. And i used Inkscape to create this? Is there a feature in inkscape i wan't aware about?

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks Praveen!!! Saved it with InkScape! You are awesome my friend!

Answer (score 0):

If `http://wefix.cf/Resources/wefix2.svg` works for all the browsers other than IE, and `http://wefix.cf/Resources/wefix.svg` works for IE, you can use conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <img src="http://wefix.cf/Resources/wefix.svg" alt="Logo" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
        <img src="http://wefix.cf/Resources/wefix2.svg" alt="Logo" />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Where conditional comments are supported by IE you mean. IE9 and below...right?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes. IE 10 and above doesn't support CC.

Comment: I have already done this but with JS so that i can identify IE 10 and 11 as well. but this does not solve the problem since i can't convert any of them to a png.